# Limit of arguments on Coalesce SQL function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a logic for ID types there are about 20 of them and I do this `IDType = COALESCE(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19))` under where clause in the query.

1) For a record with types 1 and 12. When 1 is satisfied, 12 is ignored and I see only one result (obviously two before).

2) A record has type ID 6,8,11. And I expect it to pick 6 and drop 8 and 11 types as per order specified in Coalesce but this isn't working. Interestingly, I don't find any result for this record.

Is there a limit on number of arguments in Coalesce function as in first case it was picking up 1 and ignoring 12 and in second case it didn't pick up any ID type. Please help #NewToSQL

Comment: Please tag your rdbms (sql-server, oracle, postgres, etc)

Comment: the result of COALESCE(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19) is always 1. coalesce returns the first non null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pick up "first" IDType you can do it with one of window function, say [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT t.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IDType ) rn 
FROM table1 t 
WHERE IDType IN (1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19)
) a 
WHERE rn =1;
```

Updated to add `partition by employee_id`  (assuming table has `employee_id` field)

```
 SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT t.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.employee_id ORDER BY IDType ) rn 
FROM table1 t 
WHERE IDType IN (1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19)
) a 
WHERE rn =1;
```

Comment: What this is doing is number all the ID types for all the records but only selecting (obviously) the row number 1. So, if there are 10 employees with 25 ID's. it is numbering 1 through 25 for the result set and filtering row number 1 and outputting 1 record. What I want is to return 10 employees but with only one ID type (say they all have 1 as ID type they all return in result set), correct ?

Comment: @Sanj : Updated.  I think you should have mentioned all requirements in the question, it's impossible to guess what you need unless you write it down.

Comment: Your updated answer was what I was exactly looking for, great learning !!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server COALESCE does not have explicit limitation about quantity on parameters.

Your reading your problem it sounds like a logic problem, that you must have resolve using the [Case (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql).

[COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) is to resolve null issues.

Comment: May be you are right, I am using a wrong function. What would be the better approach in my case when I want to ignore rest of the ID types when one is available ? say 2nd case where 6 is available and I want to ignore 8 and 11 types.

Comment: @Sanj Can you provide a table that shows the Id and expected result? I can’t figure a good solution with your input.